# Parse a multidimensional json array using bash

Tags: bash, json, jq

I'd like to iterate over a multidimensional json array in bash but haven't found a solution.

Here is what the multidimensional array would look like:

```
{
    "FILES": [
      [ "file1.yaml", "file2.yaml", "file3.yaml" ],
      [ "file1.json", "file2.json" ]
    ]
}
```

I'd like to convert each array into a string that will eventually be the input to a command.

So something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

Json_Array=$(cat <<EOF
{
    "FILES": [
      [ "file1.yaml", "file2.yaml", "file3.yaml" ],
      [ "file1.json", "file2.json" ]
    ]
}
EOF
)

function runCmd ()
{
  echo "command $1"
}

function runCmds ()
{
  jq -c '.FILES' <<< "$Json_Array" | while read i; do
    runCmd "$(echo $i | jq .)"
  done
}

runCmds
```

So the output should be:

```
command file1.yaml file2.yaml file3.yaml
command file1.json file2.json
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is the final objective here? Do you want something you can copy/paste to execute, or will the `command` actually be executed in the final script?

Answer (score 2):

Insert the command with any options at the start of each array, then pass each array through `@sh` to create shell code.  Evaluate the shell code.

Here, I'm also showing how to insert extra arguments to the command (`-a` and `-b hello`):

```bash
eval "$( jq -r '.FILES | map([ "command", "-a", "-b", "hello", .[] ])[] | @sh' file.json )"
```

Given the JSON in the question, this would execute the following commands in the shell:

```bash
'command' '-a' '-b' 'hello' 'file1.yaml' 'file2.yaml' 'file3.yaml'
'command' '-a' '-b' 'hello' 'file1.json' 'file2.json'
```

If you have your JSON document in some variable, `$json`, then use

```bash
eval "$( jq -r '.FILES | map([ "command", "-a", "-b", "hello", .[] ])[] | @sh' <<<"$json" )"
```

Comment: Thank you @Kusalanada this was very helpful!  It turns out I'm using the files part of the string and assigning that to a variable which I feed to a command. Interestingly the way the is formatted it keeps the "' '" and the command doesn't parse it.  However I simply just trimmed off the ticks using `| tr -d \'` on the string and it works! Learning about the `@sh` was perfect thanks!

Comment: @hickersonjl The sigle quotes should make no difference. Compare running something like `ls` with running `'ls'`. In fact, it would be crucial to keep the quotes if any of the filenames or the other arguments contain spaces or filename globbing characters.

Comment: @hickersonjl If you had wanted to parse out the filenames only, then don't pass them through `@sh`. Instead, use `@tsv` or `@csv` and then read them as tab or comma-separated values.  If you use `@csv`, use a CSV-aware tool to read the data as newlines, quotes and commas would be encoded as per usual in CSV files.  In any case, just removing the single quotes is the wrong thing to do as it would remave single quotes from the filenames too.